# creating a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file with the following format.

```
>abc
qqqwqwqwewrrefee
eededededededded
dededededededd
>bcd
swswswswswswswws
wswswsddewewewew
wrwwewedsddfrrfe
>fgv
wewewewewewewewew
wewewewewewewxxee
wwewewewe
```

I was trying to create a dictionary with (>abc,>bcd,>fgv) as keys and the string below them as values. I could extract the keys but confused about updating the values.   help me pls.

```
file2 = open("ref.txt",'r')
for line in file2.readlines():
    if ">" in line:
    print (line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d={}
key=''
file2 = open("ref.txt",'r')
for line in file2.readlines():
    if line.startswith('>'):
        key=line.strip()
        d[key]=[]
        continue
    d[key].append(line.strip())
file.close()
```

I have not tested the above code, but it should work

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean about "updating" the values, but try this:

```
mydict=[]
with open("ref.txt", "r") as file2:
    current = None
    for line in file2.readlines():
        if line[0] == ">":
            current = line[1:-1]
            mydict[current] = ""
        elif current:
            mydict[current] += line # use line[:-1] if you don't want the '\n'

In [2]: mydict
Out[2]: {'abc': 'qqqwqwqwewrrefee\neededededededded\ndededededededd\n',
         'bcd': 'swswswswswswswws\nwswswsddewewewew\nwrwewedsddfrrfe\n',
         'fgv': 'wewewewewewewewew\nwewewewewewewxxee\nwwewewewe\n'}
```

Comment: The value is complete string, not list. I mean key is abc and value is whole string(the characters below it)

Comment: your key(current variable) contains "\n"

Answer (score 1):

When you get a line value with the `'>'` in it, save the line in a variable. When you read a line *without* the `'>'` in it, add it to a dictionary entry keyed by the previously saved variable.

```
key = None
dict = {}
for line in file2.readlines():
    if ">" in line:
        key = line
        dict[key] = ''  # Initialise dictionary entry
    elif key is not None:
        dict[key] += line  # Append to dictionary entry
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = {}
with open("file.txt","r") as r:
    for line in r.readlines():
        if ">" in line:
            key = line[1:].strip()
            dictionary[key] = ""
        else:
            dictionary[key] += line

print(dictionary)
```